# Dumping real time TS data into a file

Tags: networking, real-time, real-time-data, transport-stream

I want to capture TS packets from Network and dump it into a file.Can you suggest me a tool for doing this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html). You can stream your TS and capture it in realtime, then filter out the TS packets and save them to a file.

Comment: Thanks for replying.One more doubt When I play any video over the internet data transfer is through TS packets?? So does streaming TS means Plating any video over Internet?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but I do know that as long as you can see the network traffic, you can filter out the specific video packets that you are looking for in that stream.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark would be the tool for debuging.

If you want to record multicast TS stream for later viewing, use VLC or tsdumper2.

Answer (score 0):

You should click on "Follow UDP stream" then select "Show data as" RAW, and then save it with .ts extension and you will be able to play it in VLC and other TS players.